# How can i use indexes like (^1) in String.Substring()?

Tags: c#, string, substring

```
string str2 = str2.Substring(^2);
```

This code gives me the following error:

> CS1503 Argument1: cannot convert from system.index to int

Comment: Java and C# are two different programming languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indices and ranges are used within brackets `[...]`. You don't pass an index to `Substring`; indices and ranges are a *replacement* for `Substring`.

I assume you are trying to get the last two characters from the string. That can be done with:

```
str2[^2..^0]
```

or shorter:

```
str2[^2..]
```

Please note .NET 4.x does not support indices and ranges.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes